# R retrive p-value from var.test (F test)

Tags: r, p-value

I am using 
var.test and I want to retrive the p-value. any suggestion?

```
x <- rnorm(50, mean = 0, sd = 2)
y <- rnorm(30, mean = 1, sd = 1)
var.test(x, y)
```

F test to compare two variances

data:  x and y
F = 5.6877, num df = 49, denom df = 29, **p-value = 3.839e-06**
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  2.85764 10.70096
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          5.687715

Comment: `var.test(x, y)$p.value` as you can find out by inspecting `str(var.test(x, y))` or reading `help("var.test")`.

Answer (score 6):

```
test <- var.test(x, y)
test$p.value
[1] 0.0001575875
```

Check out `test$`to see all the options for statistics

Comment: Thank you. Got it now. my real example have , p-value <
2.2e-16; then when I use test$p.value it has: > test$p.value
[1] 0; So I was thinking it does not working.

Comment: The p-value in my data is obviously different than yours due to the randomness involved in using `rnorm`

Comment: @CloverCeline When printing p-values, most R functions use `format.pval`. If p-value are within floating point precision around zero, they are displayed as smaller than that floating point precision.